# Impact of creating a non-clustered index in production database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I had a very slow webpage. Figured out the underlying stored procedure is missing a critical index.

After creating the index, the page is blazing fast and that problem is solved.

What I need to know is if creating this index in production DB table, when application is heavily used, can somehow impact users (even in a short period of time)

Index is non-clustered and table has millions of rows.

This app is being used 24 hours a day.

Our company Uses enterprise edition.

More info:
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU20) (KB5024276) - 15.0.4312.2 (X64)
Apr  1 2023 12:10:46
Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

For future reader: We deployed the Index to a table with 37 milion rows. The impact was almost none with no user reporting any slowness.

Our own tests also showed no slowness on updates or inserts.

However I must also say this table is not used Crazy heavily during the day.
Usage is average. So if you have super active table procceed with caution.

Comment: What version and edition of SQL Server?

Comment: There is no SQL Server v18.9.1 - that's a version number for **SQL Server Management Studio** - the GUI/admin tool to access SQL Server. To find the actual SQL Server version, use SSMS to execute `SELECT @@VERSION` and post the results here, please!

Comment: 18.9.1 is SSMS - we need to know version and edition of the SQL Server to know if it supports `ONLINE = ON` and `WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY`

Comment: Clearly creating the index is the right thing to do.   I suspect your users will thank you.

Comment: Is the question *what impact will index creation have in production*? Creating an indexed will block other queries unless you have SQL Server Enterprise and use `ONLINE = ON`. *BUT* 1M rows isn't a lot of data nowadays, especially if the table isn't heavily used.

Comment: Yes, usually the queries will get delayed while the index is being created unless you do a nolock. But they shouldn't crash, if you have enterprise edition you can run index creation online

Comment: OP - is the question "what is the impact while the index is being created?" or "what is the ongoing impact of that index existing?"? I read it as the latter but others seem to be answering the former.

Comment: @BenThul - "This app is being used 24 hours a day." would indicate the former to me

Comment: @MartinSmith - Similarly, "After creating the index, the page is blazing fast and that problem is solved." inferred the opposite for me. Either way, you and I are guessing.

Comment: @ Ben Thul . I already know what's the impact after index is created. My webpage is blazing fast.

Comment: Also we did not observe any slownews on updates or inserts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> An offline index operation that creates a nonclustered index acquires
> a Shared (S) lock on the table. This prevents updates to the
> underlying table but allows read operations, such as SELECT
> statements. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#online---on--off-)

So this is less blocking than a `Sch-M` lock but still you would want to actually stop any processes sending write requests to avoid blocking chains developing behind their requests for locks incompatible with an `S` lock and so potentially blocking readers anyway (less of an issue if you are using RCSI for readers though).

To avoid making the table read only for the duration you would need to specify

```
WITH (ONLINE = ON);
```

But the above requires Enterprise Edition.

There is still a problem however, the shared lock is still needed even with this (twice for a very short interval each time)

[image]

([Image Source - Online Index Operations white paper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/administrator/cc966402(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN))

and even though it only needs this `S` lock for some short periods whilst it is waiting for the shared lock a blocking chain can develop.

If you are on SQL Server 2022+ you can specify a `WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY` option to allow other queries to jump the queue ahead of it and hope that it manages to get the lock with no competition in that time period - and specify what should happen if it can't get the lock in that time.

```
WITH (ONLINE = ON 
        (WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY 
           (MAX_DURATION = 30 MINUTES, ABORT_AFTER_WAIT = NONE)
        )
     );
```

after the timeout...

- `ABORT_AFTER_WAIT = SELF` - just abandons the operation.
- `ABORT_AFTER_WAIT = NONE` - waits for the lock at normal priority so can cause blocking as before.
- `ABORT_AFTER_WAIT = BLOCKERS` - Kill all user transactions that block the online index rebuild DDL operation so that the operation can continue.

If you are not on SQL Server 2022+ you don't get this option so just have to accept that you might see some blocking at those points.

You can also consider specifying `MAXDOP` to restrict the degree of parallelism and ensure it doesn't hog all the schedulers.

Comment: MAXDOP to 6 or so is a good idea.